# Can I invest in the market portfolio of modern portfolio theory?

Tags: portfolio, modern-portfolio-theory, capm

According to the theory, the market portfolio is composed of all assets weighted by their market capitalization, and this is the portfolio one should own. Is there a way to build a portfolio close to the theory's market portfolio?

This would imply owning stocks, real estate, commodities, cryptocurrencies, art, and perhaps even derivatives, from all over the world, weighted by their respective market capitalization.

Is there an ETF or a mutual fund that approaches such market portfolio? If not, why not, given that it's optimal in first approximation? Is there at least easily accessible information of the respective market capitalization of all kinds of assets?

Comment: The best data available on what the global market portfolio looked like at the end of 2020 is by Swinkels et al. and is available for download here https://datarepository.eur.nl/articles/dataset/Data_update_The_Global_Multi-Asset_Market_Portfolio_1959_2012/9371741?file=25960496 Some categories (eg. private equity, and some others that you mention) are hard to access, but you can certainly approximate the rest with ETFs.

Comment: Thank you @noob2, this is a good start. Yet, they vastly underestimate real estate as they consider only commercial (and not residential) real estate. Also, they don't include commodities (like gold), cryptos, art... and provide only aggregated numbers. So, a good start but many missing pieces.

Comment: I agree. But if someone is going to invest their money this way, they are gong to have to make some compromises and some shortcuts. The "ideal" market portfolio is not attainable.

Answer (score 4):

This "market portfolio" is a chimera: very useful for basic reasoning and teaching, but that cannot be traded. Here are three reasons why

- the term "market" suggests that it is available on markets, but of course it is not: as you write in the question, **you should invest in a lot of unlisted, hence not public, assets**
- even if you restrict to companies: **the life cycle of companies prevent to invest in them at the beginning of their life**, when did you needed to invest in Amazon and Facebook that are now giants? before their capital was open to public
- there is in fact a structural impossibility: to spot an asset and decide it should go in your "market portfolio", it will have to grown first in capital so that you notice it (it is a matter of investors' attention), you will miss the ones that are rocketing the most (because you should spot them very quickly, indeed quicker than others). In short: **you will have to take risks**, to bet on the ones that should be part of your portfolio. But the whole idea of this market portfolio is that you can invest on it passively, i.e. without taking risk.

For more details, see [Financial Markets in Practice, From Post-Crisis Intermediation to FinTechs](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/12731), by L and Raboun.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I don't have enough credit to put a thumb up. This only partially answers my question though. Because, imagine we had a very popular mutual fund whose endeavour would be to create a portfolio as close as the market portfolio as possible. The fund would buy real estate all over the world, art pieces, invest in start-ups... So, it would make many non-marketed assets marketable. My question is thus: why isn't there such a mutual fund? Why can't I easily invest in Indian real estate or in a diversified portfolio of startups?